# Why does AsyncIO's DatagramProtocol stop responding when an error is received?

Tags: python, udp, python-asyncio

I'm working through the [Transport & Protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html) Python documentation as I would like to use AsyncIO in my applications. One of these applications I'm writing acts as a UDP server, which handedly, AsyncIO provides "built-in" support for through the `DatagramProtocol`.

Anyways, I decided to try and test the capabilities of AsyncIO and see if there were any gotcha's before I started writing said application and I found that the `DatagramProtocol` just quits accepting connections when an error occurs (i.e. the client drops before the server has a chance to respond). The `error_received` method in my server example is properly called, so I'm confused as to what is happening.

Here's some reproducible code. Both are taken from the docs above with very slight modifications to produce this issue.

**Client**:

```
import asyncio


class EchoClientProtocol:

    def __init__(self, message, on_con_lost):
        self.message = message
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost
        self.transport = None

    def connection_made(self, transport: asyncio.DatagramTransport):
        self.transport = transport
        print('Send:', self.message)
        self.transport.sendto(self.message.encode())

        # Try to force the server to raise the error
        # 'No service is operating at the destination network endpoint on the remote system'
        self.transport.abort()

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        print("Received:", data)

        print("Close the socket")
        self.transport.close()

    def error_received(self, exc):
        print('Error received:', exc)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print("Connection closed")
        self.on_con_lost.set_result(True)


async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    on_con_lost = loop.create_future()
    message = "Hello World!"

    transport, protocol = await loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
        lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, on_con_lost),
        remote_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))

    try:
        await on_con_lost
    finally:
        transport.close()


asyncio.run(main())
```

**Server**:

```
import asyncio


class EchoServerProtocol(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Received %r from %s' % (message, addr))
        print('Send %r to %s' % (message, addr))
        self.transport.sendto(data, addr)

    def error_received(self, exc):
        print("Exception thrown: %s" % exc)


async def main():
    print("Starting UDP server")

    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    # One protocol instance will be created to serve all
    # client requests.
    transport, protocol = await loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
        lambda: EchoServerProtocol(),
        local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))

    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)  # Serve for 1 hour.
    finally:
        transport.close()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Is there a better way to approach this or am I failing to understand how AsyncIO works? This server needs to be able to handle upwards of 25 connections simultaneously with all sending data.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and I also don't know why asyncio is behaving this way

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I had a similar issue.
Currently it is a bug within the Proactor eventLoop and there is an open ticket for this issue here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91227

Temporary solution is to use a selector eventLoop:

```
selector = selectors.SelectSelector()
loop = asyncio.SelectorEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```